# Ref/ label problems with custom designed List of equations

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, labels, renewcommand

Writing my thesis I needed to define a custom list of equations. The code works as expected to deliver what I need it to be.
This is how I designed the list of equations ( Not my design, I had it from another post in the forum ) :

```
\newcommand*{\ORGeqfloat}{}
\let\ORGeqfloat\eqfloat
\def\eqfloat{%
  \let\ORIGINALcaption\caption
  \def\caption{%
    \addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
    \ORIGINALcaption
  }%
  \ORGeqfloat
}
```

This is how I create an equation.

```
\begin{eqfloat}[H]
\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\dot{x}\\
\dot{y}\\
\dot{z}\\
w_{x}\\
w_{y}\\
w_{z}
\end{array}\right] = J_{6 \times n} \left[\begin{array}{c}
\dot{q1}\\
\dot{q2}\\
\vdots \\
\dot{qn}
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
\label{eq:Jacob}
\caption{Jacobian matrix of a robot arm with $n$ joints}
\end{eqfloat}
```

The equation looks fine. just the way I want It :

[image: Nodesc]

The only issue is when I try to reference it in my document, using  `\ref{eq:Jacob}`

The document renders "??" instead and I get an error saying:

You have referenced something which has not yet been labelled. If you have labelled it already, make sure that what is written inside `\ref{...}` is the same as what is written inside `\label{...}`.

I have no idea how to fix this as I'm using a custom design, that I didn't make and I'm fairly new to Latex.

Thank you very much

Comment: As always on this site you're more likely to get any help if you provide a full but minimal example instead of these sniplets where others have to add code to even be able to test your code.

Comment: My document is over 5000 lines with around 20 tex files. I just simply can't. I'm doing my best to highlight the details that I believe are relevant to my issue. that's all

Comment: You can always make a minimal example. That skill is an important debugging tool. We don't even know which preamble or class you use. Important details.

Comment: I'm using `\documentclass[oneside,12pt, inner=2.5cm,Outer=2.5cm,Top=2.5cm,Bottom=2.5cm]{Classes/aesm_edspia}` And my preambule is 95 lines long. I tried once to do it and they mentioned that my code added is too long and unreadable.

Comment: And that class is of course not a known one and this may have artefacts that may affect any solution we provide. Sorry, but we've been here many times before where we have provided a solution to a user only for them to unveil that their actual document is using stuff that they never told us about. Thus we end up wasting our time. This is why we _always_ ask for a minimal example.

Comment: Alright I'm sorry. just started using Latex a couple weeks ago. I'm just trying to write a document. And always looking through the forum for solution that might fix problems I may encounter

Comment: `\label` should go after `\caption` (or in this case `\ORIGINALcaption`).